# How to install and run lessc on top of node.js and Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, less

Hi I am learning LESS and I would like to install lessc on my Windows 7.

Following this tutorial http://verekia.com/less-css/dont-read-less-css-tutorial-highly-addictive

The first step is I dowloaded and installed node.js (node-v0.10.5-x64.msi).

Then in a console, I ran

```
npm install less -g
```

I got the following:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc -> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc
less@1.3.3 C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less
+-- ycssmin@1.0.1
```

Then I ran the following in the same console:

```
lessc style.less > style.css
```

But I got

> 'lessc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am not sure where I got wrong. I googled but it seems there is too much stuff, not sure which one is right. Did many tests without any success.

Could someone tell me how to do it or give me a pointer to some place with detailed and latest install info for Windows?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install -g lessc`? Did you run as an elevated command prompt? NPM creates a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) on the system that is added to the path.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a console, run the following:

```
node C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc style.less > style.css
```

`style.less` must be in the console's directory.

Comment: I'm by no means an experienced person when it comes to command line. Your answer was the last bit of information that was needed to get lessc working on windows. Thanks!
**Just for anyone experiencing the same strange problem: Many times I got the misleading waring that I needed to install a ruby gem called "therubyracer". This was obviously not the main problem and cost my several hours trying to install this gem.**

Comment: I found `lessc.cmd` in the `C:\Users\Me\node_modules\.bin` folder on my Windows7 box. (Using Node v0.10.29, installed via Chocolatey.)

Comment: This worked for me: `npm install less` and then `node  node_modules\less\bin\lessc  resources\less\main.less  >  output.css` — could this be a better approach if one happens to depend on a particular version of LESS? (I mean, using the local project's LESS version, not the global one in `Me\AppData\Roaming`.)

Answer (score 8):

step 1: `npm install less -g`

step 2: `npm i less --save-dev`

Comment: I upgraded my nodejs. Running these commands did the trick. thanks!

Comment: @liza could you elaborate on why this 1step is needed?

Answer (score 7):

to get lessc working you have to add

> `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm`

to the path

Comment: Then why the @#$* didn't Node do that when it installled?!

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could add the bin folder in system properties -> advanced ->environment variables and append the whole path to the bin folder by edited the Path variable.

Comment: And this solution is for Windows. Have tried it on Windows 7.

Comment: Then the sequence should be more clear: Start -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables.

Comment: Doesn't work in Powershell even when added to the PATH, but works in cmd.exe?

Answer (score 3):

If you just installed node.js, the windows PATH variable won't be updated within any running CMD windows. Try closing CMD and reopening it!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by using Node Version Manager (nvm) to install and use the latest version of Node.js

`nvm install latest`
`nvm use 12.4.0`

After that I navigated to my project folder and typed: 
`npm install less -g` and then
`npm i less --save-dev`

Finally I typed `lessc less/index.less css/index.css` to compile my less.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, don't forget to open the command line console as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

After spending around number of hours hunting around to compile less files, I got very simple answer:

1. download node-v0.10.26-x64.msi for windows users -> install it -> then
2. go to any folder(in command prompt) where *.less files are located and run the command
   "lessc styles.lsss > styles.css". (Example: in command prompt, less is my less folder where *.less files exist)
   D:\less>lessc styles.less > styles.css
3. now you will get styles.css files created automatically. Open and see styles.css file

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must have NodeJS installed on your machine, use this [link](https://nodejs.org/en/) to download and install it.

Once installed make sure to restart your machine.
Then check whether it is properly installed by running "node -v" and "npm -v" in CMD.

Once that is done run "npm install less -g" and you are ready to compile your less files.

Just go into the directory where your files are and run "lessc style.less style.css"

More can be found on this [link](http://technarco.com/install-node-js-npm-less-on-local).